# How to display Woocommerce Category image?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, thumbnails

I use this code in PHP:

```
$idcat = 147;
$thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $idcat, 'thumbnail_id', true );
$image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt="" width="762" height="365" />';
```

Where `147` is the current ID manually set, but i need to current id in other categories

Any suggest?

Comment: What exactly is the question? You need to retrieve the category image for the current category id without setting it explicitly?

Comment: Excuse my english, i need to display the image from current woocommerce product category.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

To display the category image for the currently displayed category in `archive-product.php`, use the current category `term_id` when `is_product_category()` is true:

```js
// verify that this is a product category page
if ( is_product_category() ){
    global $wp_query;

    // get the query object
    $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();

    // get the thumbnail id using the queried category term_id
    $thumbnail_id = get_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true ); 

    // get the image URL
    $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id ); 

    // print the IMG HTML
    echo "<img src='{$image}' alt='' width='762' height='365' />";
}
```

Comment: THanks you for your answer, but not work proprly, because "is_category" in woocommerce template is "is_product_category" and "get_query_var('cat')" -> "cat"?

Any suggest?

Im using woocommerce templates to override default woocommerce. And im editing the product-archive.php template.

Comment: Do you mean archive-product.php? This is the template that is used for the shop homepage as well as tag archives, for example `/product-tag/TAG-NAME`. If that is the case, I assume you are trying to get the category image for each product in the loop? Or are you viewing a single product category and need to display the image for that one category, for example `/product-category/CATEGORY`?

Comment: Yes is it /product-category/CATEGORY, when i create a new category, i can upload a image from woocommerce admin.

P. D.: in Spanish (my native language :)) is /categoria-producto/categoria

Comment: I'm in Chile now, but my Spanish is terrible. The file should be the same even with your language set to `es_ES`, so you want to use `is_product_category()` for the if statement and the category from the `term_id` since it is part of the taxonomy - see the edits to my answer.

Answer (score 9):

From the [WooCommerce page](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-display-category-image-on-category-archive/):

> ```
> // WooCommerce – display category image on category archive
>
> add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_category_image', 2 );
> function woocommerce_category_image() {
>     if ( is_product_category() ){
>       global $wp_query;
>       $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
>       $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
>       $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
>       if ( $image ) {
>           echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="" />';
>       }
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: Neat. get_woocommerce_term_meta is deprecated, use get_term_meta instead.

Answer (score 9):

get_woocommerce_term_meta is depricated since Woo 3.6.0.

so change

```
$thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta($value->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
```

into: ($value->term_id should be woo category id)

```
get_term_meta($value->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true)
```

see docs for details:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-get_woocommerce_term_meta.html

Comment: 7 years wasn't such a bad run :)

Answer (score 5):

To prevent full size category images slowing page down, you can use smaller images with `wp_get_attachment_image_src()`:

```
<?php 
$thumbnail_id = get_term_meta( $term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );

// get the medium-sized image url
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'medium' );

// Output in img tag
echo '<img src="' . $image[0] . '" alt="" />'; 

// Or as a background for a div
echo '<div class="image" style="background-image: url("' . $image[0] .'")"></div>';

?>
```

EDIT: Fixed variable name and missing quote

Comment: This code is deprecated since Woocommerce 3.6 and $term is not defined in this example

Comment: FYI the code has now been updated to replace the deprecated function call

Answer (score 4):

You may also used foreach loop for display category image and etc from parent category given by parent id.

for example, i am giving 74 id of parent category, then i will display the image from child category and its slug also.

```
**<?php
$catTerms = get_terms('product_cat', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'ASC', 'child_of'=>'74'));
foreach($catTerms as $catTerm) : ?>
<?php $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $catTerm->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true ); 

// get the image URL
$image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );  ?>
<li><img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" width="152" height="245"/><span><?php echo $catTerm->name; ?></span></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>**
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution with few code. I think is better.

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( get_term_meta( get_queried_object_id(), 'thumbnail_id', 1 ), 'thumbnail' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add code in `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/` loop path

```
    <?php
        if ( is_product_category() ){

            global $wp_query;
            $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();    
            $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true ); 
            $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id ); 
            echo "<img src='{$image}' alt='' />";
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The original answer helped but is out of date.

From https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-display-category-image-on-category-archive/

```
 /**
 * Display category image on category archive
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_category_image', 2 );
function woocommerce_category_image() {
    if ( is_product_category() ){
        global $wp_query;
        $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        $thumbnail_id = get_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
        if ( $image ) {
            echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="' . $cat->name . '" />';
        }
    }
}
```

I added a class `echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="' . $cat->name . '" class="catImage" />';` and then styled it with

```
.catImage{
  float: left;
  max-height: 100px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php 

 $terms = get_terms( array(
 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
 'hide_empty' => false,
 ) ); // Get Terms

foreach ($terms as $key => $value) 
{
 $metaterms = get_term_meta($value->term_id);
 $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta($value->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
 $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
 echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt="" />';
} // Get Images from woocommerce term meta

?>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

```
function loop_product_category_image(){
    global $wp_query;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $wp_query->ID, 'product_cat' );
    $thumbnail_id = get_term_meta( $terms[0]->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
    $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
    echo "<img src='{$image}' alt='category image' width='162' height='165' />";
}
```

You can hook than for example:
in product loop:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'loop_product_category_image', 7);
```

or in product:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'cylkow_loop_product_category_image', 7);
```

or wherever you want.

You can use also conditional tags
https://woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/

Answer (score -1):

Use this code this may help you.i have passed the cat id 17.pass woocommerce cat id and thats it

```
   <?php
      global $woocommerce;
      global $wp_query;
      $cat_id=17;
      $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "woocommerce_termmeta";
      $query="SELECT meta_value FROM {$table_name} WHERE `meta_key`='thumbnail_id' and woocommerce_term_id ={$cat_id} LIMIT 0 , 30";
      $result =  $wpdb->get_results($query);

      foreach($result as $result1){
          $img_id= $result1->meta_value;
      }     

      echo '<img src="'.wp_get_attachment_url( $img_id ).'" alt="category image">';
   ?>
```