# Check to see if WooCommerce Category Image exist

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a way to check and see if a category thumbnail exist in WooCommerce? Something similar to `has_post_thumbnail()`? I'm trying to create conditional that will display a category image if available and if not it'll display the WooCommerce placeholder.

CODE UPDATED with answer below for anyone else who needs it:

```
<?php
            $args = array(
                'number'     => $number,
                'orderby'    => $orderby,
                'order'      => $order,
                'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
                'include'    => $ids,
                'parent'    => 0
            );
            $product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
            foreach( $product_categories as $cat ) {
                $category_thumbnail = get_woocommerce_term_meta($cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
                $image = wp_get_attachment_url($category_thumbnail);

                if ($image) {
                    $image_decider = $image;
                } else {

                    $image_decider = woocommerce_placeholder_img_src();
                }

                echo '
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="'. get_site_url().'/product-category/'. $cat->slug .'">
                        '. $cat->name . '<img src="'.$image_decider.'" width="350"   height="350" alt="'. $cat->name . '-category-image"></a>
                </div>
                ';
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: This will [help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717112/how-to-display-woocommerce-category-image) or [this](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-display-category-image-on-category-archive/)?

Comment: Hi Rahil, I'm able to pull the category image with no issues using this. I guess what I'm having trouble with is setting a conditional to check if the category image exist (ie. I uploaded my own) and if not load the woocommerce placeholder.I've updated the question with a code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `if () {...} else { .. }` conditions to decide whether image exists or not.

Simply use:

```
if ($image) {
    $image_decider = $image;
} else {
    $image_decider = 'http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/your-theme/images/placeholder.png';
}

echo $image_decider; //Image Or Placeholder
```

**Full Code:**

```
<?php
    $args = array(
       'number'     => $number,
       'orderby'    => $orderby,
       'order'      => $order,
       'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
       'include'    => $ids,
       'parent'    => 0
    );
            $product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
            foreach( $product_categories as $cat ) {
                $category_thumbnail = get_woocommerce_term_meta($cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
                $image = wp_get_attachment_url($category_thumbnail);

                //Code to paste
                if ($image) {
                    $image_decider = $image;
                } else {
                    //Your placeholder image URI
                    $image_decider = 'http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/your-theme/images/placeholder.png';
                }
                //Code to paste

                echo '
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a href="'. get_site_url().'/product-category/'. $cat->slug .'">
                        '. $cat->name . '<img src="'.$image_decider.'" width="350" height="150"
 alt="'. $cat->name . '-category-image"></a>
                </div>
                ';
            }
 ?>
```

Comment: Damn, you made me feel dumb! I was totally over thinking it - thanks so much!