# How can I set the Image of woocommerce category as the background of the category title?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to set the woocommerce category image as the title background.

This is the title line in archive-product.php

```
<h1 class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>
```

I wrote

```
                <h1 style="background: url(<?php if ( is_product_category() ){
    global $wp_query;

    $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();

    $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true ); 

    $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id ); 

    echo "<img src='{$image}' alt='' width='762' height='365' />";
}   
?>);" class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>
```

I can see the image in the browser editor! But something is wrong. How could I resolve that?

Comment: The question I answered ^ should give you the answer.

Comment: Yes, I used that answer but the image doesn't appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>

            <h1 style="background: url(<?php if ( is_product_category() ){
    global $wp_query;

    $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();

    $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true ); 

    $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id ); 

    echo "'{$image}'";
}   
?>);" class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>
```

I followed [How to display Woocommerce Category image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717112/how-to-display-woocommerce-category-image) and set `echo "'{$image}'";`
instead of `echo "<img src='{$image}' alt='' width='762' height='365' />";`