# WooCommerce: How to display Category Name in single-product.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I display the category name in single-product.php?

In archive-product.php the code is:

```
<?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?>
```

but what could I use to show the category name in the single-product.php that belong to the category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
global $post;
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ($terms as $term) {
   echo $term->name .' ';
   $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true ); 

   $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id ); 

  echo "'{$image}'";
}
```

Comment: In archive-product.php I used a background with the category image (using this method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918268/how-can-i-set-the-image-of-woocommerce-category-as-the-background-of-the-categor) , Is it possible to use the category image in the single-product.php?

Comment: yes you can use that code, you have termid so you can get thumbnail.

Comment: Do I have to change something? Because like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30919324/3774595 in single-product.php it doesn't print the image

Comment: yes you have to do it like.. above .. if you want image displayed outside,, just repeat the loop again and put those three lines.

Answer (score 0):

find in `content-single-product-CATEGORYNAME.php`

```
woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
```

Change this to:

```
if (is_product_category( 'CATEGORYNAME' ) {
woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-CATEGORYNAME' );
}else{
woocommerce_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
}
```