# How to display category thumbnail on WooCommerce category page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, thumbnails

I created a WooCommerce category, added description and an image to it.

[image]

There are some products in the category too.

Looking at the category in frontend (`/product-category/mycat/`) I see category description and product images - but not a category image. I tested it with all default WP themes and with Storefront too - category image is in no theme visible.

In the rendered source code there is nothing similar to category image - after title and description comes immediately the sorting dropdown:

[image]

What I'm missing?

Shouldn't category image appear automatically on the category page?

Or should I nevertheless trigger its displaying with adding of  any code to theme file?

Indeed, the solution from *https://stackoverflow.com/a/12717177/1992004* is working for me - the category image appears.

Is there really no solution without custom code?

Comment: The default category page didn't show the image. You could check `taxonomy-product_cat.php` in the WooCommerce and the hook inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Shouldn't category image appear automatically on the category page? Or should I nevertheless trigger its displaying with adding of any code to theme file?"

**Short answer**

No it does not show up by default! It all depends on the `template/theme` developer's architecture/preferences and how s/he has planned the theme out! If you'd like to customize your theme, then you could go ahead and add it manually to your theme templates using the snippet you found!